# How to select all values that a not a number using SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Due to an earlier error, I ended up with letters and symbols in places where I should have had integers and floars. At this time, I don't know the extent of the problem and working to correct the code as we move forward.

As of right now when I run `SELECT distinct col1 from table`; I get integers, floats, symbols and letters. A few million of them.

How can I update the SQL to exclude all numbers? In other words, show me only letters and symbols.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide sample data and desired results.  It is not obvious what YOU mean by "number".

Comment: Done. Thanks Gordon. I literally mean `don't show me any integers or floats`

Comment: What is the data type of col1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`GLOB`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-glob/) operator:

```
select col1 
from tablename 
where col1 GLOB '*[^0-9]*'
```

This will return all values of `col1` that contain any character different than a digit.
You may change it to include `'.'` in the list of chars:

```
where col1 GLOB '*[^0-9.]*'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hYzTMC5MrVB4EnEtEraEj9/1).

If what you want is values that do not contain any digits then use this:

```
select col1 
from tablename 
where col1 not GLOB '*[0-9]*'
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hYzTMC5MrVB4EnEtEraEj9/2).

Comment: I don' t think that will do exactly what the OP wants.  That will return 'ABC', 'X%$#', but not 'A12C', for example.  I think the OP wants to exclude all ints and floats, so, no '123' or '1.23', which is fine, but you would also exclude things like 'AC$5Ft', which I think should be included,

Comment: It will return A12C because it contains at least 1 non digit char.

Comment: Oh, I see. My bad.

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak it's fine, you made me think about the dot. I included a demo in my answer.

Comment: Guys, I am getting only numbers here. I need everything except for numbers

Comment: @JamesRaitsev Did you check the demo? The result is everything but numbers.

Comment: @JamesRaitsev in case you want to exclude all values that contain any numeric digit then see my 2nd query.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . SQLite doesn't have regular expressions built-in, making this a bit of a pain.  If the column actually contains numbers and strings (because that is possible in SQLite), you can use

```
where typeof(col) = 'text'
```

If the types are all text (so `'1.23'` rather than `1.23`), then this may do what you want:

```
where cast( (col + 0) as text) = col
```

Comment: How do I capture symbols? Any chance I can express `not a number`?

Comment: `typeof(col)` may return `'text'` even though it contains a number like `1`